Fixing Future Warning Concat on excel files
I am using glob to retrieve a list of csv files and combine them to append to excel.
When I run the process I receive a future warning.

FutureWarning: The behavior of DataFrame concatenation with empty or
all-NA entries is deprecated. In a future version, this will no longer
exclude empty or all-NA columns when determining the result dtypes. To
retain the old behavior, exclude the relevant entries before the
concat operation.

What do I need to do to this section of my code (below) to future proof it?
QInboundCSV = [file for file in glob.glob("Queue Inbound\*.csv")]
QOutboundCSV = [file for file in glob.glob("Queue Outbound\*.csv")]

df_queue_inbound = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, QInboundCSV), ignore_index=True)
df_queue_outbound = pd.concat(map(pd.read_csv, QOutboundCSV), ignore_index=True)


Can you try excluding the columns that only contain NaN values and then concat?

@rr_goyal some columns contain both data and NaN values. If that will trigger the error I cannot exclude the columns

The error message says all-NA columns, I think if you try removing the columns that only contain NaN values, it should work.

You can filter out empty DataFrames:
df_queue_inbound = pd.concat((x for x in map(pd.read_csv, QInboundCSV)
                              if not x.empty), ignore_index=True)

Or:
df_queue_inbound = pd.concat(filter(lambda x: not x.empty, 
                             map(pd.read_csv, QInboundCSV)), ignore_index=True)

